# Editing areas in shapefile + scalebar

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3, style, area

I´m using Qgis Version 3.16

I have the following problems:
One of my layer has several areas. Now I want to give every area a different style. I already found the function to give all areas the same style.
I had an idea today in the morning that I could multiply or copy the layer and edit in every layer one area and delete the rest.
That would make a lot of effort. Does somebody has an other idea to change the areas in the same layer?

In addition, I don't find the function which you can change the graduation of the scale bar. So no 100, 200, 300, 400 steps, instead 50 100 200 400 etc.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: a proper answer will need more information: What software are you using? normally (ArcGIS, QGIS), you'll have a tab called 'symbology', where you can change the layout depending on an attribute e.g. 'area'. But without knowing what software you're using, a proper answer is really difficult...

Comment: @GevaertJoep thank you for the answer! I edited some of my post.